# How to change modal-dialogue width to 100%

Tags: reactjs, reactstrap

I am using `reactStrap`, How can i change width of modal-dialogue, i am trying to make it 100% width

I tried using 
modal-content-custom

```
<Modal isOpen={true} toggle={this.toggle} dialogClassName="modal-content-custom">
```

using inline style

```
<Modal isOpen={true} toggle={this.toggle} dialogClassName={{maxWidth:'100%'}}>
```

using custom class

```
.modal-content-custom {
    max-width: 100% !important;
}

<Modal isOpen={a} toggle={this.toggle}
                className="modal-content-custom">
</Modal
```

but its not working for me, it is not overriding the 940px of modal-dialogue

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can just add `!important` to max width in your custom `className`:

```
.modal-content-custom {
  max-width: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: tried that as well, but not getting it, question edited